# stratified random sample with counts in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I have the following table generated by a `calculate_table()` procedure:

```
table(
  id integer,
  type integer
)
```

I am looking to do a stratified random sample, where I choose a random id, randomized by type, as well as return the counts for type and counts for id.

So in the following example:

```
id,type
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,2
6,2
7,2
8,3
9,4
```

A randomization could choose the following:

```
chosen_type: 2
-- how many unique types are there overall
type_count: 4
chosen_id: 6
-- of the type matching chosen_id, how many 
-- instances are there.
id_count: 3
```

So there would be a 25% chance of getting type 2, and if type 2 is chosen, there is 33% of getting id 6.

The following wouldn't work because it is randomly choosing from all id's, independent of their type, which isn't what I want.

```
select * from calculate_table()
order by random()
limit 1;
```

I am having trouble trying to avoid calling the `calculate_table()` procedure more than once and/or storing things in arrays. How can I go about this?

Comment: Besides storing the calculate table and calling it more than once, what alternative is there?

Comment: How does "2" have a "type_count" of 4?  Your query should work.

Comment: The posted data does not match the desired output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because there are 4 distinct types to choose from. id_count is 3 because there are 3 ids with type 2 to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with t(id,type) as (values
    (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,2),(6,2),(7,2),(8,3),(9,4)
), dt as (
    select type, id
    from t
    group by 1,2
    order by random()
    limit 1
)
select
    type as chosen_type,
    (select count(distinct type) from t) as type_count,
    id as chosen_id,
    (select count(distinct id) from t where type = dt.type) as id_count
from dt;
 chosen_type | type_count | chosen_id | id_count 
-------------+------------+-----------+----------
           2 |          4 |         6 |        3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this with window functions, ordered by random().

See [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/219b6/11) for an example.

```
select  *
from   (
        select  type,
                row_number() over( order by random() ) as type_random,
                id, 
                row_number() over( partition by type order by random() ) as id_random
        from    calculate_table()
       ) as a
 where   type_random = 1
         and id_random = 1
```

Comment: why id `id_random` partitioned by `type`, where as `type_random` isn't partitioned by anything?

Comment: @baxx that was to account for this part of the question: "a 25% chance of getting type 2, and if type 2 is chosen, there is 33% of getting id 6". So by not partitioning on anything type_random=1 gets a randomly chosen record across the whole dataset (which will mean that if 25% of rows belong to that type, it will have a 25% chance of being chosen). I then partition on type for id_random so that within the rows for that type I can choose a random record